# How do I connect submit_button() to wp_insert_post() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a submit button in the admin area of WordPress, which automatically creates a new post, when I click the button.

Here is my code;

```
submit_button();

function programmatically_create_post() {       

wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  'steve',                
            'post_title'        =>  'bronco',               
            'post_type'     =>  'post'
        )
    );
}
```

I have tested the `wp_insert_post` function and it does work.

So, this adds a non-working button in the admin area and I can not figure out how to connect the submit_button to the `wp_insert_post()` function. How do I connect the button to the function for creating a new post on it click?

Comment: What does your `submit_button` function do?

Comment: Currently nothing. I would like it to pass a boolean value to the wp_insert_post() function so that when I click it I create a new post.

Comment: where you want to add that button? in the left side of admin area( menus )?

Comment: It's actually on a custom settings page that is created in the admin area by the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this either via a form or an AJAX, depending what's more convenient to you.

**The non-AJAX way**

First you create an HTML form:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_post">
    <?php submit_button('Create post'); ?>
</form>
```

Or you can simply add a button with a `_GET` parameter in the link, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=create_post">Create post</a>
```

And then you just create a hook in your functions PHP and bind it to your function, like so:

```
add_action('admin_post_create_post', 'programmatically_create_post');
function programmatically_create_post() {
    wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  'steve',                
            'post_title'        =>  'bronco',               
            'post_type'         =>  'post'
        )
    );
}
```

**AJAX way**

A link or even a div would be enough:

```
<a href="#" class="create-post">Create post</a>
```

In JS we create a click event and send a request to create a post to our server:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.create-post').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
             '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // Change this accordingly
             { action: 'create-post'},
             function(resp) {
                console.log('Request sent. Result: ' + resp);
             }
       );
    });
});
```

And finally in PHP we add the function to the hook that is triggered by our AJAX request:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_create-post', 'programmatically_create_post');
function programmatically_create_post() {
    wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  'steve',                
            'post_title'        =>  'bronco',               
            'post_type'         =>  'post'
        )
    );
}
```

This is a very basic setup, but I guess it's enough to get you going :)

Here's a link to the official documentation on [how AJAX works in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). You can enhance your request with different types of input (post type, post status etc.), but more importantly make it safer with [wp_nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) and other security measures. That's out of the scope of the question though.